# Where to use which scope in maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, scope

I have a project "framework-ws" that contains 3 modules (api, dictionary, webapp).
This project is used has a parent project for multiples other web-services project.

For example, the project "core-ws" has "framework-ws" for parent. It also contains 3 modules (api, dictionary, webapp).
Each of these modules has the framework as dependency.

- core-ws-api => framework-ws-api
- core-ws-dictionary => framework-ws-dictionary
- core-ws-webapp => framework-ws-webapp
- (subproject => dependency)

Now I have other dependencies (lombok for example) that is used in every project (framework + child-project).

I don't understand where I need the declare this dependency.

1. In the parent project with a "provided" scope, and in each
   child-project without scope
2. In the parent project with no scope, and no dependency in each
   child-project
3. Another solution that I didn't think of

The second solution seems cleaner because I don't need to duplicate the dependencies in each pom.xml. But I don't know if it's the best practice.

EDIT : Here is a picture of projects structure.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your parent pom use a dependency management section see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then in your child pom you will use the dependency but not specify a version, i.e. the version will be specified in the parent once for all children.  You still need to include the dependency in each module.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In terms of scope read this https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope the default scope is compile which is what you will usually use.  I think you are confused about the meaning of scope from readinf your question.

Comment: Thanks, that solve part of my problem. Dependency management is exactly what I need to not duplicate the code.
I still don't understand when the "provided" scope is usefull. Maybe I don't need it for my project. I will search more information about this scope.

Comment: Provided is when you want to compile against something but let something else, usually a server "provide" the implementation.  The obvious example is the servlet API.